# Python 3.x Hosting configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, server, server-configuration

Goodnight,
I have an application (API-RES) running on my local machine.
All perfect, until I want to upload my application to a hosting.

I have managed to have Flask running on my remote UNIX machine, and the console displays the typical message that accepts requests under 127.0.0.1:5000.

First of all, comment that I have written a very simple function that returns me the typical "Hello World", without the need of any library. But when I try to access via the IP of the domain or through the name of the domain under port 5000, after taking several seconds, I get an error that the server is not responding.

I have checked the proxy server but it is disabled, I am new to Python, I had previously done sites in PHP and the thing was much simpler XD.

If someone could help me, I would be enormously grateful.
Thank you !

Comment: Hi Moises - It looks like we're going to need some more explicit detail to help you out - can you provide any debug output, stack traces, exceptions, etc. that would help clarify what code and configurations you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ip to 0.0.0.0 or localhost in the app.run() method.
https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.app.Flask.run

Comment: That's correct !!!
It works !!

Thanks !!